# Additionnal warning message returns an error instead of a warning

Tags: r, rstudio

I have two functions, `f_` that throws an error and `f` that throws a warning before calling `f_`.

```
f_ <- function() stop()
f <- function() {
  warning()
  f_()
}
```

Since I have a warning before the error, R produces "additionnal warning messages", but the message in this warning is not my `f` warning but the error produced in `f_` called a 2nd time :

```
> f()
Error in f_() : 
In addition: Warning message:
In f() :
  Error in f_() :
```

It seems to works as expected if the error is produced in the same function or by a built_in function.

```
f <- function() {
  warning()
  stop()
}
> f()
Error in f() : 
In addition: Warning message:
In f() :
```

Can someone helps me to understand what is happening there ? 
Thanks for any help.
I'm running R version 3.3.2 on x86_64-w64-mingw32 using RStudio.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in R 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is caused by the Rstudio error inspector. When encountering an error Rstudio displays the possibility for traceback and debugging. I believe that is the source of the confusion (my own included). The "second" error is simply a feature in Rstudio which assists in debugging as seen below. Note the two buttons on the right allowing you to "show traceback" and "rerun with debug".

**In Rstudio**
[image]

As you can see below, if you run R in a terminal, 
this "additional" error is not there.

**In a terminal**
[image]

In your global options in Rstudio, under General tab, you can turn off the use of the debug error handler. You can also do this under Debug -> On Error.
Rstudio will then not display the "additional" message.

**Edit:**
Upon investigating a bit further, there *is* something odd going on though. Below, I tried to make the error and warning message a bit more informative with the following observations:

- Calling `f()` many times in a row, it is not entirely clear to me when the error inspector appears and when it does not.
- When the error inspector *does* appear, the warning message is not displayed. When the error inspector does not appear, the warning message is displayed.

I do not know anything about Rstudio's internals, but it is quite definitely the error inspector causing these minor issues.

[image]

Comment: Strange, yes i'm using Rstudio

Comment: To ne the results seem to be identically. Do l miss something?

Comment: thank you for the error profiling it's really helpful

Comment: @JulienNavarre Glad I could help.